# Rspec: wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am fairly new to Ruby and brand new to Rspec and am trying to make the following Rspec code pass:

```
require "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/fish"

describe fish do

  before do
    @fish = fish.new(3)
  end

  it "should report the number of fish" do
    @fish.number.should equal 3
  end
end
```

I am attempting to test the following code, which I'm sure is wrong for a number of reasons, but right now I am just trying to get past a "Wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)" error":

```
class fish
  def intialize n
    @number = n
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have spelt `initialize` wrong in your Class definition (Missed the i after the n.)

Therefore your class still has the default constructor as you haven't overridden it.
The default constructor takes no arguments so is complaining when you try and pass `3`.

Comment: Omg thank you! What a stupid mistake for me to have made ><

Comment: @aserty You should also have gotten an error from a class name that wasn't capitalized. Did you not get an error?

Comment: When I went to fix the formatting on stackoverflow I deleted the capital F and accidentally replaced it with a lowercase f, but thanks for your concern :)

Answer (score 1):

A couple things I notice right off the bat...

1. I recommend using parenthesis until you get used to Ruby's syntax.
2. You misspelled `initialize` in your class.
3. Initialize the `Fish` (and the class `Fish`, for that manner) with a capital `F`.

---

```
describe fish do
  before do
    @fish = Fish.new(3)
  end

  it "should report the number of fish" do
    @fish.number.should equal(3)
  end
end


class Fish
  def intialize n
    @number = n
  end
end
```